# CURL sleep for 3 minutes after "WAITPERFORM => PERFORM"

Tags: curl

I'm using curl on Cygwin (on Windows 7 pro)

```
curl 7.48.0 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin) libcurl/7.48.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2g zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.29 libpsl/0.13.0 (+libidn/1.29) libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.7.1
```

I'm sending REST request to a server on local network.
The result is as expected, except for the execution time.

On the detailled log, I see that it "waits for something" (for 3 minutes, always 3 minutes) just after the message "STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM".
(Same problem using the SOAP version of the service on the same server)

- The same curl request, directly from the server, is OK.
- From an other computer with seemingly identical configuration, also on the LAN, is OK.
- From my computer, I can access other services on the server with trouble (SSH, Postgresql, and even the web application on the same JBoss, same port, as the REST service that's causing trouble).
- The same request to another server on the network is OK.
- The same request to a local server (same JBoss version) on my computer is OK.

I've tried forcing --connect-timeout and --expect100-timeout to 1 second, it did not help.
If I set --max-time < 180s, curl exists before completing the request (as expected).

Does anyone have any clue as to how to troubleshot this issue ?

```
> curl --trace-ascii - --trace-time -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic bWV2ZW8uYWRtaW46bWV2ZW8uYWRtaW4=" -H "empty;" "http://172.31.52.34:8080/meveo/api/rest/provider/version?&"
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
11:09:44.192873 * STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x600057850; line 1108 (connection #-5000)
11:09:44.193896 * Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
11:09:44.258002 *   Trying 172.20.27.50...
11:09:44.258714 * STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x600057850; line 1161 (connection #0)
11:09:44.281889 * Connected to vipproxy1.prod.extelia.fr (172.20.27.50) port 8080 (#0)
11:09:44.282037 * STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x600057850; line 1260 (connection #0)
11:09:44.282150 * STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x600057850; line 1278 (connection #0)
11:09:44.282409 > GET http://172.31.52.34:8080/meveo/api/rest/provider/version?& HTTP/1.1
11:09:44.282409 > Host: 172.31.52.34:8080
11:09:44.282409 > User-Agent: curl/7.48.0
11:09:44.282409 > Accept: */*
11:09:44.282409 > Content-type: application/json
11:09:44.282409 > Authorization: Basic bWV2ZW8uYWRtaW46bWV2ZW8uYWRtaW4=
11:09:44.282409 > empty:
11:09:44.282409 >
11:09:44.283281 * STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x600057850; line 1357 (connection #0)
11:09:44.283395 * STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x600057850; line 1484 (connection #0)
11:09:44.283506 * STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x600057850; line 1494 (connection #0)
11:12:44.107389 * HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
11:12:44.107559 < HTTP/1.0 200 OK
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
11:12:44.108005 < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
11:12:44.108118 < Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
11:12:44.108228 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
11:12:44.108336 < Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
11:12:44.108446 < Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
11:12:44.108558 < Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
11:12:44.108666 < Date: Fri, 27 May 2016 11:13:26 GMT
Date: Fri, 27 May 2016 11:13:26 GMT
11:12:44.108778 < X-Cache: MISS from maiire4.docapost-bpo.com
X-Cache: MISS from maiire4.docapost-bpo.com
11:12:44.108887 < X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from maiire4.docapost-bpo.com:8080
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from maiire4.docapost-bpo.com:8080
11:12:44.109001 < X-Cache: MISS from riou.prod.extelia.fr
X-Cache: MISS from riou.prod.extelia.fr
11:12:44.109111 < X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from riou.prod.extelia.fr:8080
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from riou.prod.extelia.fr:8080
11:12:44.109220 < Via: 1.0 maiire4.docapost-bpo.com (squid), 1.0 riou.prod.extelia.fr:8080 (squid/2.7.STABLE9)
Via: 1.0 maiire4.docapost-bpo.com (squid), 1.0 riou.prod.extelia.fr:8080 (squid/2.7.STABLE9)
11:12:44.109331 < Connection: close
Connection: close

11:12:44.109448 <
11:12:44.109726 * nread <= 0, server closed connection, bailing
11:12:44.109867 * STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x600057850; line 1652 (connection #0)
11:12:44.109981 * Curl_done
11:12:44.110108 * Closing connection 0
11:12:44.110224 * The cache now contains 0 members
{"status":"SUCCESS","errorCode":null,"message":"MEVEO API Rest Web Service V4.2"}
```

Comment: As an additional note, I observe the same behaviour using python requests.